# disable clang static analyzer for certain cmake subprojects

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I have a problem integrating clang's static analyzer into cmake toolchain.

There is a big C++ project with plenty of third party libs which I want to exclude from the process of static analysis.

Let's say I have shell script with following content

```
CCC_CC=clang
CCC_CXX=clang++

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=path-to-ccc-analyzer -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=path-to-cxx-analyzer ../project_root

scan-build make -j3
```

Then I have CMakeLists.txt in third-party subdir

```
project(my_third_party)

add_library(my_third_party STATIC main.cpp)
```

How can I make clang ignore this project?

I've found through net that I need to set CXX_FLAGS in such way

```
project(my_third_party)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker")

add_library(my_third_party STATIC main.cpp)
```

But this method doesn't seem to work when `c++-analyzer` being envoked during compilation. (yes i do set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` too for C projects)

As I inderstand I need to directly invoke `clang++ --analyze` in order to be able to disable check or in some way edit `ccc-analyzer` perl script to skip analyze step.

Am I miss something? Could this be solved eaiser?=)

Comment: For scenarios using the clang analyzer through clang-tidy cmake integration (added in cmake v3.6), I _think_ this is just a matter of setting the [`<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_CLANG_TIDY) property on each target, or setting defaults on a directory scope basis using the [`CMAKE_<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html).